# jquery retrieving numbers always in english format for google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am having hidden input for google maps format such as:

```
id = SearchedLattitude with the value 45.719997
```

When I tried to get the values

```
var myLat =$('#SearchedLattitude').val();
```

But the results myLat is not consistent, If I set my browser in french default language then i get 45,719997 ( with the ,) in english I get 45.719997 (with the .)

It make my code fails because I use those values for google map api, it takes only english format number style for the position property

```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: lat and lon numbers here,
        map: map,
        title: 'Home'
    });
```

How can i make it work cross countries and localisations ?

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1):

you can just do a replace:

```
myLat = myLat.replace(/,/g, '.');
```

this will replace all `,` with `.`